# FULLTEXT search SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

table structure (type : MyISAM)

```
    user_name              varchar(30)                               
function_type              varchar(30)                                   
function_name              varchar(30)                                   
function_description       text
```

FULLTEXT :

```
KEYNAME:             TYPE:                          FIELD:
PRIMARY BTREE       BTREE                          function_name
full_text           FULLTEXT                       function_description
```

AND i have these values on the column "function_description" :

```
function_description:

akram lofaif 
that is das
akram is blum test
adnan is fine
```

And when i tried to get back some values like this :

```
SELECT * FROM functions
     WHERE MATCH (function_description)
     AGAINST ('akram' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

it did give back NOTHING !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [Fulltext Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) states, that a fulltext search for a word yields no results, if the word appears too often:

> A word that matches half of the rows in a table is less likely to
>   locate relevant documents. In fact, it most likely finds plenty of
>   irrelevant documents. We all know this happens far too often when we
>   are trying to find something on the Internet with a search engine. It
>   is with this reasoning that rows containing the word are assigned a
>   low semantic value for the particular data set in which they occur. A
>   given word may reach the 50% threshold in one data set but not
>   another.

If you're just trying it out, add some more data to your table, where the word `akram` is not included, in order to reduce the number of rows identified.

If this should be your production table, you might want to try the `BOOLEAN` mode, which does not follow the natural language limitation:

```
SELECT * FROM functions
     WHERE MATCH (function_description)
     AGAINST ('akram' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```